# 'Correct' way to have perl arguments interpreted by current shell

Tags: perl

Sorry, this is pretty basic, and I suspect a duplicate, but after some searching I'm coming up empty:

Given the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use IPC::Run3;
my $stdout2;
print $ARGV[0];
print "\n";
my @cmd1 = split /\s+/,  $ARGV[0] ;
run3 (\@cmd1, \undef, \$stdout2, \$stdout2);
print $stdout2
```

And running it like so:

```
£ perl comp.pl "md5sum *(.)"
md5sum *(.)
md5sum: '*(.)': No such file or directory
```

Fair enough.  The `*(.)` isn't being intrepreted by the shell and probably most would consider this a feature.  But I would like it to be intepreted by the current shell (or `zsh` specifically would be fine).

The question is how I can do this *without* complicating the shell command to run the perl script.

Prepending `"zsh"` and `"-c"` to `cmd1` is ok if that's a reasonable way to do it.  It just seems like...it isn't.

My intention is also to pass slightly more complex commands to this script eventually, like so:

```
perl comp.pl 'md5sum *(.)' 'ssh remoteHost "md5sum *(.)"'
```

I have no objection to non-perl answers to the problem you can probably infer I'm trying to solve (I suspect `rsync` could do this) but I'm primarily interested in solving this through Perl as there'll eventually be business-specific logic in this comparison.

**EDIT**

I tried various forms of:

```
my $cmd = $ARGV[0];
run3 (\$cmd, \undef, \$stdout2, \$stdout2);
```

the documentation seems to think this would be ok, but I get:

```
Not an ARRAY reference at /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1/IPC/Run3.pm line 320.
```

Comment: If you're ever about to write `split /\s/` then you should probably change it to `split " "` instead. This is a special case, and avoids an initial empty string in the resulting list if there happened to be leading whitespace in the object of the `split`. It is also the default value, so if you are also splitting the default value `$_` then you can write just `split` to  do `split " ", $_` which is a very common construct.

Comment: I suggest that you should use Perl itself to do the wildcarding, especially if portability is an issue. Note also that there is a module `File::Zglob` which will do the heavy lifting for you. (It has a problem with Perl v5.26 because it depends on `@INC` containing `.`, but there is an interim fix in the form of `Code::TidyAll::Zglob`.)

Comment: Thanks, especially for the 2nd comment.  I'll definitely check this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [IPC::Run3](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/IPC-Run3-0.048/lib/IPC/Run3.pm) docs say that one can pass a string instead of an arrayref for the command

> ```
> run3($cmd, $stdin, $stdout, $stderr, \%options)
> ```
>
> ...
>
> **$cmd**
>
> Usually $cmd will be an ARRAY reference and the child is invoked via
>
> ```
> system @$cmd;
> ```
>
> But $cmd may also be a string in which case the child is invoked via
>
> ```
> system $cmd;
> ```

In this case the string `$cmd` is passed to the shell if it contains shell metacharacters. So take input without splitting it, `$cmd = $ARGV[0]`, or join it after validation, `$cmd = join ' ', @cmd;`

Even in general this is *not* the preferred way, and the docs warn to see [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) for "*pitfalls*" of it.

Things are yet much worse here since you'd be passing user input directly for execution!  Never mind possible nefarious intents, just think of what a good typo can do. Even without that, there is simply a difference between typing a command at the terminal and passing it to a script, which may edit it, may get modified, pick up bugs, etc.

If nothing else, I'd urge to add code for substantial checks of submitted input.   An analysis may involve identifying the known and accepted metacharacters while suitably quoting parts of input that *shouldn't* be interpreted, for example using [String::ShellQuote](http://search.cpan.org/~rosch/String-ShellQuote-1.03/ShellQuote.pm).

But I'd really suggest to reconsider the design, so to not submit complete commands to the script. Rather, specify with keywords what should happen. Things like globbing (assembling a file list) are done from Perl really nicely and with a lot of control. Do outside only what is necessary; generally there'll be no need for the shell then.

Comment: See my updated question:  I tried the string vs array thing, basically, although I may have misunderstood the required syntax (I still often do).

Comment: @zzxyz Oh -- don't take reference if it's a string, just `run3($cmd, ...)`.

Comment: ah...ok..then I get `sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`.  And I'm assuming at this point it's using the system default shell rather than mine?  `*(.)` is `zsh`-specific

Comment: @zzxyz  Is the syntax `*(.)` valid in some shells? (What does the `.` mean there?) The `system`, which `IPC::Run3` uses, will use `sh` or whatever is used for it, most often `bash` on Linux.  In that shell you'd say `*` for all files.

Comment: In `zsh` `()` is a glob qualifier, and `.` means I just want plain files (not directories, links, etc.).  (that's from `man zshexpn`)

Comment: @zzxyz Heh, there you go ... I don't know that one can do that in bash.  You can start the `$cmd` with `zsh -c`, but then you are on your own with quoting things that you want to ensure are not interpolated. Reinforces my suggestion to consider a design whereby things are prepared (for an external command) in Perl (see edit to my answer).  In principle, I suggest do outside of Perl only what is necessary.

Comment: Yeah, this gets nasty very quickly because `zsh -c ` requires the command be quoted and therefore if the user tries to use the same quotes...badness results.  I'll check out the perl globbing for sure.

Comment: @zzxyz  (thank you for attribution)  Globbing is quite trivial.  For example, for what you said, one way: `my @files = grep { -f } glob "$dir/*";`. Add `use File::Glob ':bsd_glob';` so that spaces in names are handled. See [File::Glob](https://perldoc.perl.org/File/Glob.html)

Comment: @zzxyz, If you have a `zsh` command, you will need to invoke `zsh` instead of `sh`. `run3 $cmd, ...` is effectively short for `run3 [ '/bin/sh', '-c', $cmd ], ...`, so you want `run3 [ 'zsh', '-c', $cmd ], ...`

Comment: @ikegami - thanks.  I ended up using globbing for the local files and then `'ssh', 'host', 'md5sum file1 file2 file3'` after retrieving a remote listing.  That was tricky to get right.  But now the client is just passing local and remote paths and a host name so less breakage potential (although plenty still, I'm sure).  (Injection would be a huge issue if this program weren't for just me)

Comment: @zzxyz, I hope you actually used `shell_quote('md5sum', '--', @files)` instead of `"md5sum @files"`